# How to upload a documents creation/ last modified date in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#

I have a project where I have to upload file to a database using fileUpload.I have successfully uploaded the Name, the document itself and the extension of the document. However I need assistance in uploading the creation date or last modified date of the document to a database using file upload. Below is my how my code looks like for the upload method.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {

        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);

        string name = fi.Name;
        byte[] audioClipsBytes = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
        string extn = fi.Extension;
        //DateTime creationdate = fi.CreationTime;
        DateTime creationDate = DateTime.Today;
        creationDate = File.GetCreationTime(FileUpload1.FileName);

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UploadAudio", cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;                    //upload the name of the document to a  column  named 'name' on database
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Content", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = audioClipsBytes;    //upload the actual document to column named 'document' on database
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfAudio", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = creationDate;    
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ext", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = extn;                     //uploads the extension of the document e.g '.doc or .mp3'                 

            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    else
    {
        lblErrorMsg.Visible = true;
        lblErrorMsg.Text+=":please select file by clicking 'browse' button";
        lblErrorMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

When I run my project and and try to click on 'upload' this error is generated 'An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM'

Comment: `fi.CreationTime` or `fi.LastAccessTime`??

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in your code and look at the datetime it generate ?

Comment: I doubt the file is bringing that much file system meta data with it.  Unless the file format *itself* stores this information separately from the host file system (which I doubt), you may need some additional client-side functionality to get that information.  Perhaps the browser's file system API (HTML5/JavaScript) could be used to select the file and get information about it, and store that information in hidden form fields before submitting the form?

Comment: @ElectricRouge I would like to get the actual creation date

Comment: @RemyGrandin I have done so and it generates the current date and time

Comment: @David I kind of get what you are saying but i have no idea of how i will implement it.

Comment: @EANenz: It's a bit broad and I don't have an example handy, but it looks like there's a lot of helpful information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications  Basically what you'd do is use JavaScript to get information from the file system once the user has selected the file.  With that information you can put values into hidden form fields with JavaScript.  Then when the form is posted, those hidden form fields would have the data you're looking for.

Comment: @David Thanks, I will have a look at it